# Count Function for dynamic purpose

Tags: php

I am trying to create a generalized function that will add a number to each of my divs to make them unique.  I so far have the following code as a general idea but I would like to know what the best option would be for my purpose as I am going to implement this into a system that produces the HTML dynamically.

```
<?php
count($num);
?>

<div id ="service">
    <div class="image<?php echo $num ?>"><img src="http://placekitten.com/202/125" alt=""></div>
    <div class="title">Pussy Cat</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante elit, lobortis at fringilla vitae, bibendum at enim. Vivamus porttitor urna eget odio imperdiet accumsan sed ut mauris. Nunc magna dui, ultricies nec suscipit at, venenatis eget sapien. Aliquam a nunc laoreet massa aliquam condimentum. Phasellus euismod condimentum congue. Mauris facilisis sem a magna dapibus eu ultricies ligula elementum. Sed fermentum</div>
</div>

<div id ="service">
    <div class="image<?php echo $num ?>"><img src="http://placekitten.com/202/125" alt=""></div>
    <div class="title">Pussy Cat</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante elit, lobortis at fringilla vitae, bibendum at enim. Vivamus porttitor urna eget odio imperdiet accumsan sed ut mauris. Nunc magna dui, ultricies nec suscipit at, venenatis eget sapien. Aliquam a nunc laoreet massa aliquam condimentum. Phasellus euismod condimentum congue. Mauris facilisis sem a magna dapibus eu ultricies ligula elementum. Sed fermentum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ...

```
$num = 1;
```

... to initialize the variable *$num* and just count it up for every DIV ...

```
<?php echo $num++; ?>
```

would be the simplest to achieve what you want, i think.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop is probably the best way to do this:

```
<?php
$total = count($num);
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++):
?>

<div class="service">
    <div id="image<?php echo $i ?>"><img src="http://placekitten.com/202/125" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="title">Pussy Cat</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante elit, lobortis at fringilla vitae, bibendum at enim. Vivamus porttitor urna eget odio imperdiet accumsan sed ut mauris. Nunc magna dui, ultricies nec suscipit at, venenatis eget sapien. Aliquam a nunc laoreet massa aliquam condimentum. Phasellus euismod condimentum congue. Mauris facilisis sem a magna dapibus eu ultricies ligula elementum. Sed fermentum</div>
</div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: First of all, ID must be unique, second, these 2 divs are identical, if that is intentional, it is wrong.

Comment: @webarto Ah yes, I see what you mean now.  Fair enough.  I was trying to just answer the question asked and not 'fix' everything else going on.  Thanks for keeping us honest.  :)